# What are the consequences of dropping or changing the user name for the postgres DB account?

Tags: postgresql, security, postgresql-9.3

I feel confident I understand what's involved at the db level:

- If dropping, I'd need to create users for each sys admin, give them `SUPERUSER`, and then drop the `postgres` user.
- If changing the name, I'd need to alter the `postgres` account.

My problem, though, is that I'm not sure what the consequences of this action would be. For example, what would it mean from the point of view of the Linux `postgres` user? When I `su - postgres`, I can run `psql` and I'm able to connect to the database. I assume that capability goes away if the postgres DB user is gone.

Also, the database is started using the `postgres` linux user. Is there some issue if I remove the `postgres` user that would make it so the database wouldn't even be able to start?

From ps:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data PG_GRANDPARENT_PID=1 USER=postgres PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin PWD=/ PGLOCALEDIR=/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 PGSYSCONFDIR=/etc/sysconfig/pgsql SHLVL=1 HOME=/var/lib/pgsql LOGNAME=postgres PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data _=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgres
```

I'm running PosrgreSQL 9.3 on Cent OS 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux `postgres` user is entirely different from the `postgres` database user. It's created via the rpm package. When you're logged in as the system `postgres` user, it assumes the database user and database name that you're wanting to connect to is the same as the operating system user that you're attempting to connect from. That's why a simple psql works, and logs you into the database as the `postgres` user and `database`.

The `postgres` database is just a copy of `template1`. You can delete it or recreate it with few problems. You won't be able to drop the `postgres` user, however, because it's required by the database system.

```
user1@[local]:5432:user1:=# DROP ROLE postgres;
ERROR:  cannot drop role postgres because it is required by the database system
Time: 50.570 ms
user1@[local]:5432:user1:=#
```

However, you can block the login of the user by setting all the connections that you use to `reject` for the `postgres`, which will keep users from using that particular user for login, instead of their assigned users.

Comment: Can the postgres username be changed to something else? It seems like the db start command also specifies the user.

Comment: The username in the database should be ok to change. The startup script should be referring to the `postgres` system user rather than the database user.

Comment: Wouldn't I also have to set a password for the newly renamed user? How would the DB relate and trust the Linux account at that point? It's set up to use "peer" in pb_hba.conf.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The authentication method would change. You could change to a different auth method in your `pg_hba.conf` (like md5 and set a password), or you could set an entry in [pg_ident.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-username-maps.html) which maps the system `postgres` user to the new database user.

Comment: I've renamed our postgres user on our staging server and most things seem ok. We're getting an error in our logs on PostgreSQL startup, though: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126675/after-renaming-postgres-user-getting-role-postgres-does-not-exist-in-logs-o

Comment: Actually, I take back the comment that renaming is ok. Sorry. =( Renaming will break one very important thing. The [statistics collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html), which is needed for `autovacuum`, since there are files in `pg_global` which are created via `initdb` with the initial superuser name in them. You'd need dump, reload, and do an `initdb` with the superuser name changed if you want to correctly change the superuser's name without errors.

Comment: Hmm. So I did what you suggested and created a new db. Still seeing a FATAL error in the logs that references a postgres user: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/126926/45820