# Specify a different username for default Postgres user

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have the same issue as:
[Specifying a username while running initdb causes error in log on start of PostgreSQL process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126926/specifying-a-username-while-running-initdb-causes-error-in-log-on-start-of-postg/126939#126939?newreg=77007c9fbf4949cc8cbe32c1fe0aac32)

but I am working on setting up PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 17.04 instead of CentOS. I've read that calling `initdb` directly in this environment is discouraged because the suite of tools packaged with the software such as `pg_createcluster`, etc. What differences should I consider if I try initializing with a user other than the default postgres user?

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that calling initdb directly in this environment is
>   discouraged because the suite of tools packaged with the software such
>   as pg_createcluster

Yes, but `pg_createcluster` can pass through options to `initdb`, so it makes no difference on the configurability.

From the manpage:

> SYNOPSIS
>         pg_createcluster [options] version name [-- initdb options]

Example:

```
# pg_createcluster 9.5 test -- --username=daniel
Creating new cluster 9.5/test ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.5/test
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/test
  locale en_US.UTF-8
  socket /var/run/postgresql
  port   5433

# pg_ctlcluster 9.5 test start
Redirecting start request to systemctl

# su daniel -c 'psql --cluster 9.5/test -l'
                               List of databases
   Name    | Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
-----------+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 postgres  | daniel | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | daniel | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/daniel        +
           |        |          |             |             | daniel=CTc/daniel
 template1 | daniel | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/daniel        +
           |        |          |             |             | daniel=CTc/daniel
(3 rows)

# pg_dropcluster --stop 9.5 test
Redirecting stop request to systemctl
```